# How to extend expiration time of SOAP header message timestamp

Tags: java, soap, timestamp, cxf, ws-security

Is there a way to prolong time to live(expiration time) of a SOAP message header timestamp to prevent
"WSSecurityException: The message has expired" exception. The default is set to 300 seconds(5 minutes). We would like to extend it to 10 minutes.

We have a java ee(jdk 1.8.0_77) service that uses SOAP messages to communicate with android client.
It runs on Jboss Wildfly 10.0.0. server, and uses Apache CXF(version 3.1.4) WS security to handle messages. wss4j security policy is version 2.1.4
We have wsdl file, Custom WS-Security Endpoint (server-endpoint-config.xml file), and our Schema.xsd file. I don't know what parts of those files are relevant, so I'll provide them if someone needs more info.
I've tried using a custom interceptor that extends WSS4JInInterceptor, but that part of code never gets executed.

```
@WebService
        (
                portName = "HelloPort",
                serviceName = "BampayService",
                wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/BampayService.wsdl",
                targetNamespace = "http://bampay.bamcard.ba/",
                endpointInterface = "ba.bamcard.bampay.Hello"
        )
@EndpointConfig
        (
                configFile = "WEB-INF/server-endpoint-config.xml",
                configName = "Custom WS-Security Endpoint"
        )
@InInterceptors(// I added this part
    interceptors = {"ba.bamcard.helpers.MyInterceptor"}
)
```

and the code of MyInterceptor

```
public class MyInterceptor extends WSS4JInInterceptor {

    @Override
    public int decodeTimeToLive(RequestData reqData, boolean timestamp) {
//        return super.decodeTimeToLive(reqData, timestamp);
        return 600;
    }
}
```

If needed, I will gladly provide any additional information.
If anyone can help me, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Add this property to your server-side security settings to the value you want.

```
ws-security.timestamp.timeToLive
```

If you think you are seeing clock-skew between the client(s) and the server as part of the reason for the errors, you'll also want to account for clients that send messages with timestamps in the future.

```
ws-security.timestamp.futureTimeToLive
```

ref: https://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-securitypolicy.html

Comment: I added the above lines to the file server-endpoint-config.xml, but the error is still there.
This is what I added:

'<property>
      <property-name>ws-security.timestamp.timeToLive</property-name>
      <property-value>600</property-value>
    </property>'

Is this file where it is supposed to be, or is there another one I need to edit?